# Multiple CSS transitions happening at once

Tags: html, css, button, web

I am trying to make a button, when clicked, fade out and shrink in the width at the same time, but I only get the opacity easing with the transition and the width instantly.

Here is the website it is on, [here it is.](http://survival.endercraftservers.com) It's the Skype chat button at the bottom.

And here is the CSS:

```
div.skypediv{
     transition: all 3s;
     -webkit-transition:all 3s; /*Safari*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div.skypediv{
 -webkit-transition:all 700ms ease;
 opacity:0.7;
-webkit-transform:rotate(20deg) scale(0.9) translate3d(10px,10px,0);
}
div.skypediv:hover{
 opacity:1;
-webkit-transform:rotate(0deg) scale(1) translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't help, I want it to collapse when it gets clicked, _along_ with the opacity changing.
For example, here is my HTML:
`...onClick="this.style.opacity='0'; this.style.width='0'"...`

Comment: @cocco Please avoid code only answers.  A little explanation goes a long ways.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid changing many styles with javascript.
Toggle the class and use something like Skype as an id.

```css
#skype{
-webkit-transition:all 700ms ease;
-webkit-transform:scaleX(1);
opacity:1;
}
#skype.hide{
-webkit-transform:scaleX(0.5);
opacity:0;
}
```

Then with javascript do something like:

```js
document.getElementById('skype').onclick=function(){this.classList.add('hide')}
```